# RxJS higher order map - how to make it work?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

```
const observable$ = combineLatest([searchAPI$, searchByID$]) // Line 1
        .pipe(
            map(data => {
                let APISearchResult = data[0]; // This is an array of SearchResult type
                const searchByIDRawData = data[1]; // This is an array of Opportunity type

            // Create an array of Observable of Search Result for each of the Opportunity type
            const searchByIDSearchResults$ = searchByIDRawData.map(s => this.CreateSearchResultItemFromOpportunity(s, keywordSearch)); // Line 7
            
            return combineLatest(searchByIDSearchResults$)
            .pipe(
                map(searchResults => {
                    return APISearchResult.concat(searchResults); // Combine the output from APISearchResult with searchByIDSearchResults$
                })
            )
        }))
    
    return observable$;
```

I have two Observables (as shown in Line 1) that I want to combine the output.

In Line 7, it is an array of Observables to be emitted to convert the output from `Opportunity` type into `SearchResult` type.

At the end, the final output should be `SearchResult[]` when subscribed.

Unfortunately `observable$` is of type `Observable<Observable<SearchResult[]>>` instead of `Observable<SearchResult[]>`.

Where have I gone wrong with my mapping?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a **SwitchMap** instead of a Map on line 3. You shouldn't return an Observable in a Map because it directly passes it further in the chain without handling it like an Observable. Maps are used to chain an transform Non-Observable values while SwitchMap (and other maps) are used to chain Observables.